# how to fix a "TCL error" in Tkinter Python ? working on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, interface, frontend

i'm building a database application, currently working on the frontend interface and encountering a problem, trying to set a "scrollbar" on a 'listbox'. what do i need to do?

i use jupyter notebook and my demonstrator uses "Atom", do i need to import a certain function? i ran a previous code an "interactive converter" and it pops up its window along with this current code, so its confusing.....

```
from tkinter import *

# user interface

window = Tk()

list1 = Listbox(window, height=15, width=28)
list1.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=3)

sb1 = Scrollbar(window)
sb1.grid(row=3, column=1)

list1.configure(window, yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

window.mainloop()
```

Error message:

> TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        48 sb1.grid(row=3,column=1)
>        49 
>   ---> 50 list1.configure(platform,yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
>        51 sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)
>        52
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter__init__.py in configure(self, cnf, **kw)
>   1483         the allowed keyword arguments call the method keys.
>   1484         """
>   -> 1485         return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)    1486     config = configure    1487     def cget(self, key):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter__init__.py in _configure(self, cmd, cnf, kw) 
>   1474         if isinstance(cnf, str):    1475             return
>   self._getconfigure1(_flatten((self._w, cmd, '-'+cnf)))
>   -> 1476         self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))    1477     # These used to be defined in Widget: 
>   1478     def configure(self, cnf=None, **kw):
>
> TclError: unknown option "-class"

Comment: did you try to run it normally in console/terminal, not with Jupyter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed `window` as a parameter in `list1.configure` which is not required. Also you need to specify `sticky` location if you use `grid` on your scrollbar.

```
from tkinter import *

# user interface

window = Tk()

list1 = Listbox(window, height=15, width=28)
list1.grid(row=3, column=0)

for i in range(30):
    list1.insert(END,i) #dummy data

sb1 = Scrollbar(window)
sb1.grid(row=3, column=1,sticky="ns")

list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
mybot = Tk()

mybot.geometry("300x600")
mybot.title("MyChatBot")

pic = PhotoImage(file = "bott.jpg")
img = Label(mybot, image = pic)

img.pack(pady = 10)

mybot.mainloop()
```

Generates this Error:

> TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "bott.jpg"
>       my problem .couldnot solve yet.